# Flutter cli points to wrong directory

Tags: windows, flutter

When I tried to run my flutter project I got this error:

[image: flutter run error]

This was strange because my terminal is already pointing to the root of my project and there is pubspec.yaml file. Since I was working on a existing project, I tried to test it by creating a new flutter project. When I run flutter create I got this error:

[image: flutter create error]

For some reason flutter points to c:/Windows instead of the current folder that I am in. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by doing following steps:

- Go to Registry Editor. You can find it in Windows search or by pressing "Windows key" + R. Type in "regedit" and it will open.
- After that, got to "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor", find AutoRun key and delete it.
- If there is no AutoRun key, it might be located in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" instead of
  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"

Hope this helps.